# minecraft block durability

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I was thinking, is it possible in minecraft, using only vanilla minecraft, plugins and resource pack to make items or blocks with durability? for example stick with durability or cobblestone with durability?

I am trying to use the new 1.9 snapshot functionality to change texture depending on their durability. I would like if to know if it is possible without using any tools such as sword, axes...

Thanks

Comment: Don't think this is possible with just vanilla.

Comment: ok thanks, I will think about something else then :)

Answer (score 1):

Just for the purposes of having an answer,

This is not possible with Vanilla.